# Whats faster for streaming videos. Embedding youtube or using html5 and cloudfront?

Tags: html, youtube, streaming, amazon-cloudfront

So I want to stream a video to my site and if possible use html5's preload attribute to make it feel snappier.  But what is faster in the end, youtube or my own way using a video tag and cloudfront as the CDN?

Youtube is easier, and will be the fallback for an old browser, but I don't think I can do a preload.

I could do a JS play/pause onload to get the streaming started, but thats hacky.

Answer (score 1):

Youtube perfectly preloads videos. You can verify this by playing any Youtube video in your browser.

The loading time of a video file depends on your own location, what ISP you are using and where the nearest CDN exit point is. I.e. how near the file is stored in internet relative to you.

Answer (score 0):

I would say HTML5 would be better, Youtube is in itself moving to HTML5, Visit www.youtube.com/html5